# reverse geocoding locality returns nil on device, works on simulator

Tags: swift, ios-simulator

I don't know how or why this is happening, is there anyway around it?

crash is happening in this method

```
  func getLocation(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    guard let longitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude) else {
        return
    }

    guard let latitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude) else { return }


    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    print(location)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        print(location)

        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]
            print("locality is \(pm.locality)") //prints: locality is nil
            completion(pm.locality!) //crash: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

}
```

and calling this function in viewDidLoad like this

```
  getLocation( completion: {
        locality in
        self.city = locality
            print("youre living in \(self.city)")
    })
```

Like I said this works perfectly in the simulator (my location setting is a city bicycle ride)

I'm open to solutions, if there is any better way to get the user city.

Comment: you want only city name ?

Comment: yes only the name of the city to restrict some features.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have written `completion(pm.locality!)` has done Forced Unwrapping. You try to access the locality property of pm, by placing an exclamation mark after locality to force the unwrapping of its value, you trigger a runtime error, because there is no value to unwrap.Forced Unwrapping is done only when your are sure that it contains a value.

Optional chaining is an alternative to forced unwraping which is done by placing question mark sign after the optional value.For example

```
 if let locality = pm?.locality {
   print(locality)   
 }
```

This tells Swift to “chain” on the optional pm property and to retrieve the value of locality if pm exists. 
If you are still confused about optional you can get detail information [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

```
func getLocation(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

guard let longitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude) else {
    return
}

guard let latitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude) else { return }


let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
print(location)

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    print(location)

    if error != nil {
        print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }else{
        var address:String = "Not Found"
        let placeArray = placemarks

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark?
        placeMark = placeArray?[0]
        // Street address
        if let street = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString {
            address = street as String
        }
        // City
        if let city = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["City"] as? NSString {
            address += "," + (city as String)
        }

        completion(address)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: its safely unwrapped and obviously not crashing, but the city is still not found, even though 'country', 'street','address' are fine and working, strange, have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: found it, my city is under "state" for some reason, thanks for the answer

Comment: it doesn't worked for me as well. not even in simulator. what the hell is happening with city?

Comment: I think placemark of the location you are trying to retrieve does not contain the the value of city.It is not sure that the placemark of the location contain all the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude)

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            // Place details
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
            placeMark = placemarks?[0]

            // Address dictionary
            print(placeMark.addressDictionary)

            // Location name
            if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Name"] as? NSString {
                print(locationName)
            }

            // Street address
            if let street = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString {
                print(street)
            }

            // City
            if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? NSString {
                print(city)
            }

            // Zip code
            if let zip = placeMark.addressDictionary!["ZIP"] as? NSString {
                print(zip)
            }

            // Country
            if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? NSString {
                print(country)
            }

        })
```

Comment: its safely unwrapped and obviously not crashing, but the city is still not found, even though 'country', 'street','address' are fine and working, strange, have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: found it, my city is under "state" for some reason,  thanks for the answer.